# Applying wavelet on wave file with "WaveletStudio"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, matlab, wavelet

I try to calculate `wavelet` of wave file by using `WaveletStudio` on VS but this library doesn't have a good documentation and i'm not sure with everything i've done.

This is my code on matlab

```
[cA,cD]= dwt(x1(:,1),'sym6');
```

Here is the code on VS

```
var sample = buf.Samples;
double[] doubleArray = Array.ConvertAll(sample, x => (double)x);

Signal sign = new Signal(doubleArray);
var wavelet = MotherWavelet.LoadFromName("sym6");
var output = DWT.ExecuteDWT(sign, wavelet,2, 
SignalExtension.ExtensionMode.AntisymmetricHalfPoint);
```

Can someone help me please?
Thanks.

Output matlab : 
`3,16320801207017e-07
-1,01583359677462e-05
-3,47844682047843e-06
1,14694820511622e-05
3,39252240372775e-07
8,97279990863433e-06
1,15038653611192e-05
2,43046421129216e-06
-1,61369908206498e-05
1,32412854950234e-05
-1,08862917135995e-05`

output in VB : 
I display ten values, there are not equals with matlab and came twice(index 0 and 1)

```
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)

{
   Console.WriteLine(i+1 + ":"+outp.Index + ":" + outp.Details[i]+"/"+outp.Approximation[i]);
}
```

Result :

`1:0:7,50333128962666E-12/5,22959453519434E-12
2:0:6,99174051987939E-12/-2,27373675443232E-12
3:0:-0,00603299645041488/-0,0119133972440295
4:0:0,0176316128041094/0,0577649713181927
5:0:0,275122803422278/0,338946061095385
6:0:1,59854478815328/0,0463692277272685
7:0:1,36137312350019/-0,375410807828075
8:0:2,13904808509892/-0,78662450165757
9:0:2,47515837787779/0,143557755120469
10:0:2,87600721658731/-0,470215164047318
1:1:-2,54640752928026E-12/2,51247911364771E-11
2:1:0,000429548238281896/0,000848231716076953
3:1:-0,00137176124392235/-0,00434269860886616
4:1:-0,0158419918038213/-0,0162915354128472
5:1:0,106233502223414/0,414332125854799
6:1:-0,0322026601468124/-0,644760986507663
7:1:0,415925143582185/-0,331935864398247
8:1:0,439402584889281/-0,221799790585692
9:1:0,0682131291286869/0,25486845639989
10:1:-0,316755136430771/-0,081470480363123`

Comment: did you try to compare outputs?

Comment: when i try to display output on VS, i've a string array null

Comment: here is code of output `foreach (var outp in output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(outp);
    }`  and result is `WaveletStudio.Wavelet.DecompositionLevel`

Comment: Have a look for Tests in the Repository source, it may help: https://github.com/walteram/waveletstudio/tree/master/trunk/src/Tests/WaveletStudio.Tests

Comment: Thanks @M.Hassan hope that it should help me but no positive response.